# Calculating Manhattan distance in Python without result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two data frames in python and I'm trying to calculate the Manhattan distance and later on the Euclidean distance, but I'm stuck in this Manhattan distance and can't figure it out what is going wrong. 
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
ratings = pd.read_csv("toy_ratings.csv", ",")
person1 = ratings[ratings['Person'] == 1]['Rating']
person2 = ratings[ratings['Person'] == 2]['Rating']

ratings.head()
    Person Movie Rating
0   1      11   2.5
1   1      12   3.5
2   1      15   2.5
3   3      14   3.5
4   2      12   3.5
```

Here is data inside the `person1` and `person2`

```
print("*****person1*****")
print(person1)

*****person1*****
0     2.5
1     3.5
2     2.5
5     3.0
22    3.5
23    3.0
36    5.0

print("*****person2*****")
print(person2)

*****person2*****
4     3.5
6     3.0
8     1.5
9     5.0
11    3.0
24    3.5
```

This was the function that I have tried to build without any luck:

```
def ManhattanDist(person1, person2):
    distance = 0
    for rating in person1:
        if rating in person2:
            distance += abs(person1[rating] - person2[rating])
            return distance
```

The thing is that the function gives 0 back and this is not correct, when I debug I can see that it never enters the second loop. How can I perform a check to see the both rows has a value and loop?

Comment: Please indicate your expected output. Between what rows/points should the distance be computed?

Comment: Between the ratings, I want to see which of two persons are like each other. Creating a score by adding the distance.

Comment: Which output do you get? Which output did you expect?

Comment: if you want to see which of two persons are like each other shouldn't you take into account the movie and then compare the scores?

Comment: Because of the indentation in return, ManhattanDist will only return the distance of the first rating in person1 if the if statement is true. By the information of the data frame, i think the if statement should be a comparison between movies.

Comment: The if statement is to check if person2 has a rating, if not it should begin with the next rating in person1.

Answer (score 2):

I think the function should give back (= return) the distance in any case: either the distance is zero as initiated, or it is is somethhing else. So the function should look like

```
def ManhattanDist(person1, person2):
    distance = 0
    for rating in person1:
        if rating in person2:
            distance += abs(person1[rating] - person2[rating])
    return distance
```

I think the distance should be built by two vectors of the same length (at least I cannot imagine any thing else). If this is the case you can do (without your function)

```
import numpy as np

p1 = np.array(person1)
p2 = np.array(person2)

#--- scalar product as similarity indicator
dist1 = np.dot(p1,p2)

#--- Euclidean distance
dist2 = np.linalg.norm(p1-p2)

#--- manhatten distance
dist3 = np.sum(np.abs(p1-p2))
```

Comment: I get various errors like: `module 'numpy' has no attribute 'norm'` and `----> 8 dist3 = np.sum(np.abs(p1-p2))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (6,)` numpy is importerd and other functions like np.array() works fine.

Comment: (1.) sorry, it is `dist =np.linalg.norm(p1-p2)` . Ask google with _numpy norm_  for that. (2.a.) from the python point of view it is clear, that p1 and p2 MUST have the same length. "could not broadcast" tells you, that the lengths are different, 6 and 7. (2.b.) As I mentioned already: from the mathematical point of view, it does not make any sens if the distance is not built by 2 vectors of the SAME length, it would just be not defined. So you have 2 options: (a.) make sure that you get out of your data 2  vectors of the same length, or (b.) think about what measure model really should be.

Comment: I think it's better to put them in dictionary and then loop over check if a row has value and if so perform the Manhattan calculation.

Comment: you can compare the length n1 and n2 of p1 and p2 too with `n1=p1.shape[0]` and `n2=p2.shape[0]`

Comment: Comparing the length has nothing to do with Manhattan distance, if a row has value for both persons then it should be calculated, if there is a value missing in a row then the row should be skipped. I thought the function I wrote can take care of this, but I was wrong.

Comment: you need 2 one-dimensional vectors of the same length. See here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cityblock.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cityblock

Answer (score 0):

You function is returning 1 value ... It should (I guess) return a list of values.

Comment: No it should return one value and that is the distance of one person to another person. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry